# Place AVPlayerViewController inside UIView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

Currently I am having a dialogue view with four controls at the bottom. Each control is loading a different view inside the dialogue. One of these controls is setting an `AVPlayer` inside the dialogue view and is playing it. Unfortunately the `AVPlayer` itself comes without playback controls.

The `AVPlayerViewController` how ever does have playback controls. **Is it possible to place a** `AVPlayerViewController` **inside a** `UIView` **so that it does not get started as a new screen?**  I would like to place it inside my `UIView` so that everything is taking place inside my dialgoue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can initialize the AVPlayerViewController and add it as a child to your ViewController , and insert it as a subview.

```
[self addChildViewController:yourPlayerViewController];
[self.view addSubview:yourPlayerViewController.view];
[yourPlayerViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

And to remove it:

```
[yourPlayerViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[yourPlayerViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[yourPlayerViewController removeFromParentViewController];
```

**EDIT SWIFT METHOD:**
[Check here for Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276561/adding-a-view-controller-as-a-subview-in-another-view-controller)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Swift 3.2 / Xcode 9.2 / iOS 11

This is how to do it in 9 easy steps. The steps are explained above each line

**Make sure you `import AVKit` to have access to the AVPlayerViewController or you won't be able to use it

```
// 1. to have access to the AVPlayerViewController import AVKit
import AVKit

 // 2. create your class properties
var videoUrl: URL?
var player: AVPlayer?
let avPVC = AVPlayerViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // 3. make sure the url your using isn't nil
        guard let videoUrl = self.videoUrl else { return }

        // 4. init an AVPlayer object with the url then set the class property player with the AVPlayer object
        self.player = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl)

        // 5. set the class property player to the AVPlayerViewController's player
        avPVC.player = self.player

        // 6. set the the parent vc's bounds to the AVPlayerViewController's frame
        avPVC.view.frame = self.view.bounds

        // 7. the parent vc has a method on it: addChildViewController() that takes the child you want to add to it (in this case the AVPlayerViewController) as an argument
        self.addChildViewController(avPVC)

        // 8. add the AVPlayerViewController's view as a subview to the parent vc
        self.view.addSubview(avPVC.view)

        // 9. on AVPlayerViewController call didMove(toParentViewController:) and pass the parent vc as an argument to move it inside parent
        avPVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 4 - Subview Method**

The initial method works alright, but I feel like the view controller method seems messy when I really just want a subview.  So, most of the time I play the video in a custom view (rather than using the entire AVPlayerViewController).

I use this method to show the video in a subview which completely fills an existing view.  In the example below, **urlToVideo** is the URL to the video that you want to play, and **existingView** is the view we want to place our new view into (as a subview).

First, create a **VideoPlayerView** class in a new **VideoPlayerView.swift** file, with this, which is directly copy/paste from [Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayerlayer), except that I called it ***VideoPlayerView*** rather than ***PlayerView***.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

/// A simple `UIView` subclass that is backed by an `AVPlayerLayer` layer.
class VideoPlayerView: UIView {
    var player: AVPlayer? {
        get {
            return playerLayer.player
        }

        set {
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }

    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }
}
```

Then, when I want to play the video, I create the subview and play it:

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: urlToVideo)

let playerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: existingView.frame.width, height: existingView.frame.height)
let videoPlayerView = VideoPlayerView(frame: playerFrame)
videoPlayerView.player = player
existingView.addSubview(videoPlayerView)

player.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to have your view like a canvas and basically draw the AVPlayerViewController on top of it:

```
@IBOutlet weak var layerVideoView: UIImageView!
    guard let url = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "santana", ofType: "mp4") else { return debugPrint("video not found") }
    let path = URL(fileURLWithPath: url)
    
    let player = AVPlayer(url: path)
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.player = player
    playerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: layerVideoView.frame.origin.x, y: layerVideoView.frame.origin.y, width: layerVideoView.frame.width, height: layerVideoView.frame.height)
    self.addChild(playerController)
    self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
```

LayerVideoView is an image view, but you can use just a UIView if that suits.
Its is important to add constraints in the Storyboard to your View because your Video Player will mimic the shape of your View.