# Add a view controller as a subview in another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, carbonkit

I have already read this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276561/adding-a-view-controller-as-a-subview-in-another-view-controller) , but not working for me. I want to show a `viewController` as a subview in another `viewController`.

Here is my code -

```
import UIKit
import CarbonKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CarbonTabSwipeNavigationDelegate {

 @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let items = ["All",  "WOMEN",  "MEN",  "KIDS",  "HOME",  "CITY"]
        let carbonTabSwipeNavigation = CarbonTabSwipeNavigation(items: items, delegate: self)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.insert(intoRootViewController: self)
    }

    func carbonTabSwipeNavigation(_ carbonTabSwipeNavigation: CarbonTabSwipeNavigation, viewControllerAt index: UInt) -> UIViewController {

        //           let screen = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "demo") as! demo
        //           showSubViewContrller(subViewController: vc)
        //           return screen

        let storyBoard = getStoryBoardByIndentifier(identifier: "All")
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AllViewController") as! AllViewController
        showSubViewContrller(subViewController: vc)
        return vc
    }

    //Subview Controller
    func showSubViewContrller(subViewController:UIViewController) {
        self.addChildViewController(subViewController)
        subViewController.view.frame = containerView.frame
        self.containerView.addSubview(subViewController.view)
        subViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

    func getStoryBoardByIndentifier(identifier:String)->UIStoryboard {
        return  UIStoryboard.init(name: identifier, bundle: nil)
    }

}
```

I have a `NavigationBar` and a `tapBar`. Would like to show the `viewController` inside the view in a `container`.

[image]

But when the view loads it's coverUp/hide the tabBar.

[image]
[image]

How to solve this and show the `viewController` in my specified container.
Project Link - [GitHub](https://github.com/rashed008/banik)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow i am able to fix your issue with below changes:

Replace this method `carbonTabSwipeNavigation.insert(intoRootViewController: self)` with `carbonTabSwipeNavigation.insert(intoRootViewController: self, andTargetView: containerView)` in `viewDidLoad`

Note : Give `UITaBar` bottom constraint to SuperView not SafeArea:

[image]

Add below code in ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        tabbar.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
```

After doing this when you run you will `UITabBar`:

[image]

Comment: @MdRashedPervez Worked for you?

Comment: thank you very much for your kind help. It works for me :) . But another problem occurs - when the tabBar view appears on the container the segment header is gone . Could u help me on this. :)

Comment: I have checked Tabbar is not causing issue. Look like there is problem with `carbonTabSwipeNavigation.insert(intoRootViewController: self, andTargetView: containerView)`