# Addding UIView between tabBar and Navigation view in UITabBarController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am working on a project that uses a `UITabBarController` for displaying all the different `UIViewControllers` but now I need to add a mini player just in between the `tabBar` and the navigation view (`ViewControllers` will have to resize too).

Is there anyway I can achieve that by reusing the existing class?

**EDIT**
I have tried 2 methods:

1- Adding it into the view. Gets Added but above of the VCs

```
let aView = UIView()
view.addSubview(aView)
aView.backgroundColor = .white
aView.anchor(top: nil, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: tabBar.topAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, size: .init(width: 0, height: 100))
```

2- Adding it into the tabBar. It might sound silly but I thought It would work.

```
let viewOverTabBar = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
viewOverTabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
tabBar.addSubview(viewOverTabBar)
```

Comment: what did you tried?

Comment: @ShauketSheikh does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         super.viewWillAppear(animated)
         self.createSmallPlayer()
    }

    func createSmallPlayer() {

        let viewOverTabBar = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.tabBar.frame.origin.y-40, width: self.tabBar.frame.size.width, height: 30))
        viewOverTabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown

        //viewOverTabBar.layer.cornerRadius = viewOverTabBar.frame.size.height/2
        viewOverTabBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
        viewOverTabBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
         viewOverTabBar.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
        viewOverTabBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: -5.0)
        viewOverTabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5

        //tabBar.addSubview(viewOverTabBar)
        view.addSubview(viewOverTabBar)
    }
}
```

[image: Mini Player on Tabar]

And make sure that your all other view controller(which will navigate within tabbar) adjust frame accordingly.

1. Either you have to manage bottom view of all view controller by 30 pixels up and keep 30 pixels space blank at bottom, so no any content hide behind your player view.
2. Or you have you add :

   - Container view `UIView` same as added player view.
   - In that you have to add view controller's view with navigation controller as subview(Refer this : [Adding a view controller as a subview in another view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276561/adding-a-view-controller-as-a-subview-in-another-view-controller)).

Answer (score 2):

Add your view as subview to view of UITabBarViewController not tab bar itself. Just place it above tab bar.

Also change:

```
aView.anchor(top: nil, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: tabBar.topAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, size: .init(width: 0, height: 100))
```

to setting directly frame property of your view. 
Also you need to do in in viewWillAppear method.

Comment: Yes. And you need just to configure offsets for embedded VC. Otherwise you need to add your view as subview to to embedded VC.

Comment: how do I change the offset?

Comment: I mean that you need to offset the content of embedded VC. Simply by constraints inside embedded VC.

Comment: @NikR, could you explain why it should be in `viewDidAppear`. I add it in `viewDidLoad` at first, and then UITabBarViewController get a new shadowed item. Like we are add a new item tab on it.