# Swift - present UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am trying to present a View but the rest should just stay the same. I think it's easier to understand with some pictures:

[image]

If the user clicks on a cell on that view, this view should pop up. But the bottom bar + the "add"-Button should just stay there.

[image]

If I just `present` the view the bottom-bar "pop-up" as well but I don't want that. I hope my problem is clear. I am grateful for every help!

Comment: Look into view controller containers.

Comment: Use a tabbar controller for the + button.
Use navigation controller with custom transition (like cover vertical) for inside changes.

Comment: actually  a `ContainerView` is exactly what I need. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: wait, I have another problem now. I added a `containerView` and it appears properly but I can't click on my `cells` anymore as if the containerView would be above it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to add the vc as a subview and make its view behind the plus button view as if you tried to present it , it'll cover everything even if it's modal , follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276561/adding-a-view-controller-as-a-subview-in-another-view-controller)

Comment: the link was the answer :)