# Scrollview not scrolling / Trying to add view to bottom of content

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

So I've added a scrollview to my view controller programmatically and added some views.

```
func setupScrollView() {
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
    scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.contentSize = contentView.frame.size
}

func addUserAndFollowView(id: String) {
    userAndFollow = UserPfAndFollow(id: id)
    if let userAndFollow = userAndFollow {
        userAndFollow.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        contentView.addSubview(userAndFollow.view)
        self.contentView.bringSubviewToFront(userAndFollow.view)
        userAndFollow.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        userAndFollow.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        userAndFollow.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        userAndFollow.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        
    }
    
}

func setImageViewConstraints() {
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    if let userAndFollow = userAndFollow?.view {
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userAndFollow.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    }
}

func addLabelConstraints() {
    self.albumTitle?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.albumDescription?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    albumTitle?.numberOfLines = 2
    albumDescription?.numberOfLines = 3
    albumDescription?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false

    albumTitle?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 14).isActive = true    
    albumTitle?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    albumTitle?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    albumTitle?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
   
    albumDescription?.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    albumDescription?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: albumTitle!.bottomAnchor, constant: 9).isActive = true
    albumDescription?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    albumDescription?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

All these views show up the way I want them to with the scrollview not scrolling but when I add this next view (which is a tableview in a view controller) at the bottom of the rest of my views it doesn't show up. Possibly why the scrollview isn't scrolling.

```
func addViewController() {
        if let viewController = viewController {
            contentView.addSubview(viewController.view)
            setVCConstraints()
        }
        
    }
    
    func setVCConstraints() {
        viewController?.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewController?.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        viewController?.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: albumDescription!.bottomAnchor, constant: 7).isActive = true
        
        viewController?.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        
    }
```

What can I do to make this view appear and have my scrollview scroll all the way down this view controller and it's array content and no more or less?

Answer (score 0):

**Before** you add the view, you have

```
contentView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.contentSize = contentView.frame.size
```

So, of course, the `contentView` has a size of the `scrollView` and thus will not scroll. It is the same size.

**After** you add the view, you have

```
viewController?.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
viewController?.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: albumDescription!.bottomAnchor, constant: 7).isActive = true
        
viewController?.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

Note, above, that you define a *top* *bottom* and *width* -- there is no LEFT-TO-RIGHT indication where the `viewController.view` should start on the horizontal path. This can result in some VERY weird behaviors.

Yet, you STILL don't modify the `contentView.contentSize` to be any bigger than the `scrollView` size.

To make something *scroll*, you need the `contentView.contentSize` to be bigger than the `frame.size`.

Comment: I added `scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.frame.size.width, height: 1000)` just to test things out which made it scrollable but after adding leading and trailing anchors to the viewController.view, it still doesn't show up.

Comment: You have 2 different problems going on here. To which are completely unrelated. The first being your contentsize = scrollview size. Your next being you need to look up how to add a viewcontroller view as a subview. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276561/adding-a-view-controller-as-a-subview-in-another-view-controller